# Qual é o certo: "faz um dia", ou "fez um dia"?

Tags: gramática

Como faço para entender o porquê de as pessoas dizerem "faz um dia" se me parece que o dia já se foi e "se fez um dia"? Estariam as duas formas certas?

Comment: Renan, podes editar a pergunta para incluir contexto? Qual o resto do texto à volta dessa parte da frase?

Comment: Para mim a pergunta não é completamente clara, tenho dificuldade em compreender o contexto em que *"faz um dia"* é usado. Dar um ou dois exemplos ajudaria a compreender.

Comment: **Faz um dia que fiz a pregunta. Ontém, fez um dia que tinha feito a pergunta**. Credo.

Comment: @Lambie, desculpa, mas os falantes não usam de modo tão simples assim.

Comment: @Schilive Por favor, deixa de dizer bobagem. Fiz duas frases ótimas. E ontém ele fez uma péssima.

Answer (score 1):

O tempo verbal depende do momento em que o período em questão acaba (é completo).

> - Faz dois anos que não o vejo.
> - Amanhã faz/vai fazer/fará dois anos que não o vejo.
> - Ontem fez dois anos que não o vejo.
> - Nessa altura, fazia dois anos que não o via.
> - Ontem teria feito dois anos que não o via (mas vi-o).

Comment: Afinal de contas, você o viu ou não?

Answer (score 0):

- Fez um dia bonito.
- Faz um dia ensolarado.
- Amanhã fará um dia de chuva.

*"Amanhã fez um dia de sol"* depende do conjunto de palavras e pode soar errado.

Answer (score 0):

"*Faz um dia bonito*", nesta frase o verbo está no tempo presente, então quer dizer que "faz" agora, hoje, signfica "está um belo dia".

"*Fez um dia bonito*", aqui está no tempo pretérito perfeito, então é passado, "Ontem fez um dia bonito".

Comment: Como ficaria com as frases “faz um dia que eu não como alecrim” e “fez um dia que eu não como alecrim”? Ou ainda “hoje faz um dia que eu não como alecrim” e “hoje fez um dia que eu não como alecrim”? Eu pergunto mais de curiosidade, pois não tenho ideia de como responder.

Comment: na primeira frase *“faz um dia que eu não como alecrim”* tem um "hoje" omitido ai, como na outra frase *"[hoje] faz um dia que eu não como alecrim”*, ou seja, ambas se referem a hoje, tempo presente. Já as frases *“fez um dia que eu não como alecrim”* e *“hoje fez um dia que eu não como alecrim”* não soam bem, eu não usaria dessa forma, me parece até errado, talvez *“hoje está fazendo um dia que eu não como alecrim”* ou ainda *"ontem fez um dia que eu não como alecrim"* seria melhor, porque "fez um dia" está no passado.

Comment: Ricardo, interessante que não me soam mal. Soam-me normais. Até porque “hoje matei um monstro” funciona, já que coisas podem ter acontecido hoje, assim como ir acontecer e estar acontecendo. Eu estou mais falando o que me vem à cabeça do que realmente pensando muito sobre, então, não confies muito nestas palavras.

Comment: olha amigo está misturando as coisas, estamos falando do verbo "fazer" na pergunta e agora deu um exmplo do "matar", apesar dos tempos serem os mesmos soa muito diferente, se quiser faça um pergunta sobre tempos presente/passado e podemos falar melhor disso, é como discutir faz/fazem, é outro contexto

Comment: Ricardo, o que eu quis dizer é que “hoje fez 8 anos que eu comi alecrim” pode estar dizendo que eu comi alecrim há mais de 8 anos, porém, ontem menos de 8 anos, podendo hoje de manhã ter feito 8 anos que eu comi alecrim, mas agora são 20:30, por exemplo. Parte de hoje já pode ter acontecido.